# Element appearing on load and then disappears

Tags: javascript, scroll, fadein, scrolltop

I'm making a horizontal scrolling site. I'm using this script for letting an element fade in when user scrolls past 1500px.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scroll(function () {
var x = $(this).scrollTop();
if (x > 1500) {
$('#form_1_container').fadeIn(150);
} else {
$('#form_1_container').fadeOut(150);
}
});
</script>
```

Problem is: on page load the element appears. When I start scrolling it disappears and re appears when I hit 1500px. I want it to be invisible until I reach 1500px.

This is the site: http://stilld.nl/brrreuk/

Comment: it fades out after u scroll, the good thing will be by setting the init state to not visible and then fade in if u reach ur target Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vhzGQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `display:none` to it ( `#form_1_container` ) in CSS .

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
     $('#form_1_container').hide();
});
```

The above code will hide it when the page loads.

Else in terms of CSS:

```
#form_1_container {
     display: none;
}
```

Both will hide the form container initially. When the scroll event is triggered, once 1500 is crossed the form container will be visible.